# Writing worker using sidekiq for activerecord class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, sidekiq

I have two model classes as follows:

```
class FileInfo < ActiveRecord::Base
  STATUS = {:UNAPPROVED => 1, :APPROVED => 2, :PROCESSED => 3 }
  attr_accessible :id, :status
  validates :status, :inclusion => {:in => STATUS.values}    
end
```

`FileInfo` has id and status fields. Each file can multiple file-entries (rows) of the type `FileEntry`. `FileEntry` has id, file_info_id (foreign key of `FileInfo`) and status fields.

```
class FileEntry < ActiveRecord::Base
  STATUS = {:UNAPPROVED => 1, :READY => 2 , :SENT => 3 }
  attr_accessible :id, :file_info_id, :status, :reason
  validates :status, :inclusion => {:in => STATUS.values}
end
```

I want to write a worker to asynchronously process all files whose status field is `APPROVED` (`FileInfo` model). Each of the thread should process all file-entries for that particular file whose status is `READY`. The thread should finish once all the entries are processed for that file. Assuming that File-entries having status `UNAPPROVED` will also become `READY`.

Once each entry is processed, its status should be updated as `SENT`. Once all the file-entries all have `SENT` status for a particular file, update that file's status as `PROCESSED`.

I have code this much so far. Not able to figure out how to code the worker:

```
class FileInfoObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
  def after_save(file_info)        
    if file_info.status.eql? 2
       FileProcessingJob.perform_async(file_info.id)    
    end
  end
end
```

The worker is as follows:

```
class FileProcessingJob
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  def perform(file_id)
    puts "job"
    flag =1    
    while flag==1
      count = 0
      FileEntry.where("file_info_id = #{file_id}").find_each do |file_entry|
        if(file_entry.status == 2)
          puts "update" //Some PUT request, instead wrote a puts statement
          FileEntry.update(file_entry.id, :status => 3)
        elsif(file_entry.status == 0 || file_entry.status ==1)
          count = count + 1
        end
      end
      if(count == 0)
        flag = 0
      end
    end
  end 
end
```

Is this correct way of doing it? How to enable retry mechanism? Is this code thread-safe?

Comment: Can someone comment on this? It looks good to me. How do we ensure thread-safety? Can FileRow updation happen in batches instead of single update at a time?

Comment: whats `FileRow`? is `FileEntry`?

Comment: Oh my bad. It is FileEntry. I have edited it.

Answer (score 1):

For retry mechanism,

Just add this line, after "`include Sidekiq::Worker`"

```
sidekiq_options queue: :default, retry: 1
```

Seems its not a multithreaded web-server environment. So don't worry about thread-safety here.

Sample for multithreaded web-server environment:
[How get best performance rails requests parallel sidekiq worker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22316102/how-get-best-performance-rails-requests-parallel-sidekiq-worker/22318961#22318961)