# Sidekiq worker best practices for recurring jobs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I'm trying to define what the best/most efficient way is to schedule background jobs on sidekiq. I need this jobs to run periodically (i.e every 15 minutes, every day, etc.) for each user.

The jobs are tied to several objects such as calendars, postings, blogs, etc. Each user can have 0-many of those objects.

I have considered two options:

1) Have a scheduler job that in turn schedules a background worker for each one of the objects above. The worker would look something like this:
`

```
class WorkerScheduler
    def perform
      CalendarWorker.perform_async
      BlogWorker.perform_async
      ##### etc...
    end
```

`

and inside each worker, I would go through the process for each one of the available records (that may require threading as discussed here: [How get best performance rails requests parallel sidekiq worker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22316102/how-get-best-performance-rails-requests-parallel-sidekiq-worker)
`

```
class CalendarWorker
    calendars = Calendar.all
    calendars.each do |calendar|
      #### actions for each calendar
    end
    ### reschedule worker
    CalendarWorker.perform_in(15.minutes)
  end 
end
```

`

2) Every time a new record is created for calendars, postings, blogs, etc. Schedule a background worker and within that worker, reschedule to perform again later as desired. I.e:
`

```
    class CalendarWorker
      def perform(i) 
        .... complete all logic for Calendar.find(i) ...
        CalendarWorker.perform_in(15.minutes, i)
      end
    end
```

`

Are either of the above better than the other? I'm looking to make sure this is done in the most efficient way and also that my worker dyno (Heroku) does not get overloaded. Right now, I've been scheduling a job offer record and my memory seems to be making out the hey Dyno at just under 500 MB and there is little to no traffic. Does the number of scheduled jobs have a big impact on memory usage?

Are there other potential ways to do this both for the job running itself and the scheduling?

Comment: I've used https://github.com/moove-it/sidekiq-scheduler with great success in many projects. Have you taken a look at it?

Comment: I haven't. That seems great for the scheduling piece. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: @JoshBrody - have you been able to use the scheduler with environment specific schedules? I've gotten it to work hard coded, but haven't been able to use variables for the interval schedules